# loading AND saving to txt/csv file?

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to set up tabulator with all it's data validation goodness and simple to use UI in order to help a colleague with CRUD operations on a .txt file he has to do on a daily basis.

I found that tabulator can load data using AJAX but my question is, is it possible to load the data from a .csv/.txt file and then save to the same file?

I know you can export to .csv but without overwriting the loaded data, next time all his work would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a file on a users local computer then im afraid there is no import from file functionality built in to tabulator, but there is nothing to stop you implementing that bit your self.

The link below is a link to an article that explains how to load a CSV file from an input element in JavaScript,. In the example it loads it into an HTML table, but you could easily alter that to dump it into an array of objects to pass into Tabulators ***setData*** function

http://codeanalyze.com/Articles/Details/20174/Read-CSV-file-at-client-side-and-display-on-html-table-using-jquery-and-html5

In terms of saving the data back to the users computer, you would need to use the built in ***download*** function, there is no way to save it back to the users computer without the file popup due to browser safety constraints.

But i will add that the above approach is a bit unorthodox. The usual way to handle data persistence would be to save the data back to your server into a database, and then load it back to the client with an ajax request, giving the user the option to download the data when they want the final copy